# pandas aggregate sum of two columns and make it as one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, aggregate, multiple-columns

I am looking for solution to group by and then find the sum of two columns in pandas dataframe and display as one column.

Sum of Net and Gross column for each row and add a new column 'Total' as teh sum of both.

Sample dataset as below

```
    Name  state    Net  Gross
    A1    TN       100     60
    A2    AP       200     40
    A3    KAR      300     -10 
    A1    TN       10      60
    A2    AP       20      40
    A3    KAR      10     -10
```

Expected output

```
    Name  state    Total Amount
    A1    TN       230     
    A2    AP       300     
    A3    KAR      290
```

I have tried as below in two steps as below

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Name', 'State', ]).agg({'Net': 'sum', 'Gross':'sum'})
df2['Total Amount'] = df2['Net'] + df2['Gross']
```

Is there a way to do this in a single step.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one step we can do `melt` first

```
df.melt(['Name','state']).groupby(['Name','state']).value.sum().reset_index()
Out[56]: 
  Name state  value
0   A1    TN    230
1   A2    AP    300
2   A3   KAR    290
```